# Given an ASCII character code, how do I encode it as UTF-8?

Tags: go, utf-8, ascii

I need to convert my generated ASCII character codes in Go.

My generated codes are as follows:

- 0 (1-9 are missing, probably useless)
- 10 (11-31 are missing, probably even more useless)
- 32
- 33
- 34
- ...
- 124
- 125
- 126

How do I convert them to the corresponding UTF-8-encoded characters?

Comment: ASCII 0-127 in UTF-8 is 0-127. There is no conversion required.

Comment: You can find detailed information for each character e.g. at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/07/index.htm (that's the link for U+0007; adapt for other codes).

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to turn the ASCII code into an actual character.. for example turn 97 into "a"

Comment: I dearly recommend you to get accustomed with what "character code" and "encoding" really stand for, and where the "UTF-8" encoding is placed on that picture. There are two go-to piceces of documentation on these matters: start with [this one](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars.html) then continue with [this](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html). As to the problem at hand, @matt.s gave the correct answer: the UTF-8 encoding was created with an explicit goal of being compatible with US-ASCII, so you can read your character codes "as is".

Comment: As to "...turning to characters" -- it's just a matter of interpretation. If you have `var a byte = 97` and then use `fmt.Printf("%v", a)` the `fmt` will see your `a` variable has the type `byte` and will *assume* you want the *number* 97 printed. But if you will make sure to either stuff this code into a string value or directly ask `fmt.Printf` to *interpret* your byte values as a character, you will get character printed -- [see for yourself](http://play.golang.org/p/BFFL4GCSFN). Again, I recommend to absorb the docs I pointed you at.

Comment: Understanding utf8 as per Sami's assertion above. The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4 is really worth a watch

Answer (score 1):

The numeric values are the bytes.  You can directly convert those to strings.

```
b := []byte{97,98,99,68} // The ascii codes of abcD
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Comment: Thank you very much matt.s <3!